# Use DI inside the DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm using ef core 6 and I want to get a service from DI inside my db context. This is my DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var myService = this.GetService<IMyService>();
        // Do some stuffs before saving with myService
    
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    
        return result;
    }   

}
```

The `IMyService` and `MyDbContext` already introduced with the DI:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>(); 
services.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

The service doesn't inject, and this line throws an error:

`var myService = this.GetService<IMyService>();`

Error:
`Cannot resolve scoped service 'IMyService' from root provider`

What should I do? Do I miss something?

Comment: Why do you think you need it in the first place? Why are you overriding `SaveChangesAsync`? As for how to use it, the same as any other DI service - add the dependency in the constructor. When a new DbContext gets constructed, the DI container will add the correct service

Comment: Why are you overriding `SaveChanges` though? If you want to intercept commands or audit changes, you can [use the appropriate interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) by implementing `IDbCommandInterceptor`, `ISaveChangesInterceptor`, `IDbConnectionInterceptor` or `IDbTransactionInterceptor`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wanted to cache some entities before saving them. I have a `cacheService` and I need to cache every adds, updates and deletes.

Comment: A DbContext already caches the objects it tracks. If you write `myContect.Customers.Find(123)` you'll get back the cached object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried to get it from the constructor, but I got this error:
`The DbContext of type 'MyDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions or has more than one constructor.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I have another database to cache. That is Redis.

Comment: You didn't say anything about pooling. DbContext pooling is a recent and actually pretty small optimization. It's also something that can't work with the kind of caching you want - pooling means the DbContext instance can be cleaned and reused in other transactions. *Caching* by definition means you keep uncleaned state between those transactions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251911/discussion-between-vahid-moshtaghian-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: You're mixing up concepts that belong to different layers. As for `No I have another database to cache.` what does that mean? DbContext caches its objects. That's not optional or configurable, that's the very reason DbContext exists. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a disconnected Unit-of-Work and multi-entity Repository. It keeps track of its objects and their changes, and saves all of them when the UoW commits, ie when you call `SaveChanges`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is ok but I want to save my changes in another database for some reason.

Comment: Define `some reason` because the assumed solution may be wrong. First and second level caching aren't new or unknown concepts. EF Core has no second-level caching for a reason  - it's easier to have the application cache objects than trying to get the ORM to do the job. Quite often what you want is to cache query results, not individual objects, especially when LINQ is involved and the data you load *doesn't* match the table rows.

Comment: There are some NuGet packages that add second-level caching like [EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor](https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor). Notice that caching is added as an interceptor through the `DbContextOptions` with `AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SecondLevelCacheInterceptor>()));`. That class is a `DbCommandInterceptor`

Answer (score 2):

DI works the same way with DbContexts as any other injected service - by adding the dependency as a constructor parameter.

From the comments it seems that what you actually want is to use second-level caching (between sessions/transactions/Units-of-Work) with EF Core. This isn't available out of the box and in general, is a concept that isn't as popular now as it was some years ago. ORMs aren't used to talk to non-relational databases so applications use separate object caching at a higher level instead.

There are some NuGet packages that do add second-level caching to EF Core, for example [EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor](https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor). This project uses [EF Core DbCommand interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) to track and cache the data loaded or persisted by EF Core. The landing page examples show how to use either in-memory or Redis caching.

Once you configure caching, adding it to a DbContext is easy :

```
    public static class MsSqlServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddConfiguredMsSqlDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
                    optionsBuilder
                        .UseSqlServer(
                            connectionString,
                            sqlServerOptionsBuilder =>
                            {
                                sqlServerOptionsBuilder
                                    .CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalSeconds)
                                    .EnableRetryOnFailure()
                                    .MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MsSqlServiceCollectionExtensions).Assembly.FullName);
                            })
                        .AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SecondLevelCacheInterceptor>()));
            return services;
        }
    }
```

The relevant part only adds the DbCommand interceptor `SecondLevelCacheInterceptor`

```
.AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SecondLevelCacheInterceptor>()));
```

The package allows caching the results of specific queries :

```
var post1 = context.Posts
                   .Where(x => x.Id > 0)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                   .Cacheable(CacheExpirationMode.Sliding, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

It can also be configured to cache all queries:

```
        services.AddEFSecondLevelCache(options =>
        {
            options.UseMemoryCacheProvider().DisableLogging(true).UseCacheKeyPrefix("EF_");
            options.CacheAllQueries(CacheExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        });
```

Specific queries :

```
        services.AddEFSecondLevelCache(options =>
        {
            options.UseMemoryCacheProvider().DisableLogging(true).UseCacheKeyPrefix("EF_")
                /*.CacheQueriesContainingTypes(
                    CacheExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), TableTypeComparison.Contains,
                    typeof(Post), typeof(Product), typeof(User)
                    )*/
                .CacheQueriesContainingTableNames(
                    CacheExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), TableNameComparison.ContainsOnly,
                    "posts", "products", "users"
                    );
        });
```

Or avoid caching specific queries

```
        services.AddEFSecondLevelCache(options =>
        {
            options.UseMemoryCacheProvider().DisableLogging(true).UseCacheKeyPrefix("EF_")
                    // How to skip caching specific commands
                   .SkipCachingCommands(commandText =>
                            commandText.Contains("NEWID()", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        });
```